# sub-millisecond pause in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, sleep, pause

I am trying to do some instrument control using Python, and I want to take the instrument reading once every, say 0.001 second. How can I pause the program / wait till that time has elapsed with high enough accuracy? (will need sub-millisecond accuracy if I want the interval to be 0.001s?) I read that time.sleep() is not very accurate, so I want to know if it is possible to get that level of accuracy.

Comment: Consider [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Comment: you can check the Timer class from https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects. You can initiate timer rather than pause the program. pausing the program make the time management too unaccuracy.

Comment: @Vel From`threading.py`: "The scheme here sleeps very little at first, longer as time goes on, but never longer than 20 times per second (or the timeout time remaining)." So, it will not be substantially more accurate than `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Be sure to check that your system is capable of measuring sub-ms accurately (using a RT_PREEMPT kernel for example).

Comment: Trying to do this in python will likely lead to much heartache. Suggest some sort of dedicated HW.  Best is if the instruments themselves have a sample rate and will buffer results.